# How do I write a multivariate objective function for use with scipy.optimize.minimize() so that it can also be plotted with matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a function for which I would like to find a global maximum. Written as a python function, it looks like this:

```
def fh(x,sign=1.0):
    x1 = x[0,:]
    x2 = x[1,:]
    out = (np.sin(x1 - x2/8)**2 + np.sin(x2 + x1/8)**2)/(np.sqrt((x1 - 8.6998)**2 + (x2 - 6.7665)**2) + 1)
    return out
```

It was written (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043124/2531042)) such that it is easy to plot using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D as m3d

x = np.linspace(-20,30,num=250)
y = x
dim = np.size(x)

xx = np.zeros((2,dim,dim))

xx[0],xx[1] = np.meshgrid(x,y)

zz = fh(xx)

fig = mplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xx[0,:],xx[1,:],zz,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

The trouble is that `scipy.optimize.minimize()` can't work with this function, because it passes a vector with the shape `(n,)` to it. The result is an error:

```
<ipython-input-25-2e1bca04325c> in fh(x, sign)
      2 
      3 def fh(x,sign=1.0):
----> 4     x1 = x[0,:]
      5     x2 = x[1,:]
      6     out = (np.sin(x1 - x2/8)**2 + np.sin(x2 + x1/8)**2)/(np.sqrt((x1 - 8.6998)**2 + (x2 - 6.7665)**2) + 1)

IndexError: too many indices
```

One way to approach this problem is to use a conditional in the objective function to check the size of the input before referencing it, but this strikes me as ugly and not very efficient.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize()` works with functions that return a scalar, and it will find the `x, y` pair that provides the function's minimum. In this case, you don't pass the arrays `x[0, :]` and `x[1, :]`, only an initial guess for scalars `x, y`

Comment: But I am not passing `x[0,:]` or `x[1,:]` to `minimize()`. The error happens because `scipy.optimize.minimize()` itself iterates using inputs to the objective function of shape `(n,)`. So I have to find some way of accommodating this. A conditional will do it, but it requires extra computational effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcasting (see e.g. here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

In your case, changing the function to

```
def fh(x,sign=1.0):
    x1 = x[0]  # changed
    x2 = x[1]  # changed
    out = (np.sin(x1 - x2/8)**2 + np.sin(x2 + x1/8)**2)/(np.sqrt((x1 - 8.6998)**2 + (x2 - 6.7665)**2) + 1)
    return out
```

will work for inputs of shape (2,) and (2,n), i.e. minimizing and plotting.